# PowerShell while loop when function returns value

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have several steps in powershell invoked against sql server.

1. backup database
2. add database to availability group
3. turn on NAV middle tier

Problem is, that add to availability group step just executes command and does not wait until database is recovered on secondary nod. I have a function to check state of database on secondary and this function should wait until database is online and then start NAV middle tier.

I get correct database state (ONLINE/RECOVERING...), ,but somehow I cannot figure out WHILE part. My example here runs even if database is ONLINE or OFFLINE.
What Am doing wrong?

```
function get-dbstate($db_name_restore){
        
    $query_check_state = "select state_desc from sys.databases where [name] = '"+ $db_name_restore +"'"
    $state = invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance server2 -Query $query_check_state -ErrorAction Stop
    return $state.state_desc
}

 
while(get-dbstate($db_name_restore) -ne "ONLINE"){
            
    write-host("...still restoring")
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok correct syntax is to put function into brackets:

```
while((get-dbstate $db_name_restore) -ne "ONLINE"){

    write-host "...still restoring"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2          
}
```